# Wrapping WriteToText Within DoFn

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to wrap `WriteToText` within a `DoFn` to allow for some customization/flexibility in how I write files. Specifically, I want to write different files based on the on an argument/input (based on value provider argument). This is the code I have so far:

```
class WriteCustomFile(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self,input,output):
        self.input = input
        self.output = output

    def process(self, element):

        import re

        def FileVal(path):
            File1Regex = re.compile(r"[^\w](testfile)[\w]+(\.csv|\.txt)$")
            File2Regex = re.compile(r"[^\w](tester)[\w-]+(\.csv|\.txt)$")
            PathStr = str(path)

            if File1Regex.search(PathStr) != None:
                return "file1"
            elif File2Regex.search(PathStr) != None:
                return "file2"        

        File1Header = "Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5"
        File2Header = "Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header7,Header8"

        if FileVal(self.input.get()) == "file1":
            yield WriteToText(self.output.get(),shard_name_template='',header=File1Header)
        elif FileVal(self.input.get()) == "file2":
            yield WriteToText(self.output.get(),shard_name_template='',header=File2Header)
```

When I call this DoFn from within the pipeline, it does not write a file. What can I do to get this DoFn to work or is there a better way to handle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here the best thing to do is probably partition your input into multiple PCollections (either using [Partition](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#partition) or a DoFn with [multiple outputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs)), and write each one out separate.

More generally one can use [Dynamic Destinations](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#writeDynamic--), but this is not yet supported for Python.